# Looping through a string of numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Hey guys working on a problem from CoderBytes. The directions of the following:

Using the JavaScript language, have the function DashInsert(num) insert dashes ('-') between each two odd numbers in num. For example: if num is 454793 the output should be 4547-9-3. Don't count zero as an odd number.

Use the Parameter Testing feature in the box below to test your code with different arguments.

So I didn't create a function but here is my road map.

```
num = 3333333333
arr = num.toString().split("")
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] % 2 === 1 && arr[i + 1] % 2 === 1){
        num.toString().replace(arr[i].toString() + arr[i+1].toString(),
                    arr[i].toString() + "-" + arr[i+1].toString())
    }

    }
```

The thing is when I run this it only puts a dash between the first two threes. I really can't figure out why this is happening. Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: semi-colons (`;`) are your friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, this simple solution should do well:

```
var num = 3434333333
var arr = num.toString().split("");
var finalStr = "";
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] % 2 === 1 && arr[i + 1] % 2 === 1){
        finalStr += arr[i] + "-";
    }
    else {
        finalStr += arr[i];
    }
}
```

simply keep a string for the result, if two consecutive numbers are odd append an extra "-" after the number in the string, otherwise simply append the number and your final string will contain the desired result.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6680mgb/)**

Comment: you're welcome and dont forget to mark the answer correct as well (:

Comment: The limit should be `i < arr.length - 1`  then just concatenate the last number at the end since there is no point in testing it. Consider: `finalStr += arr[i] + (arr[i]%2 && arr[i+1]%2? '-' : '');`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG you're right but that one liner would have got a little complex for any beginner to understand so i kept it as simple as i could..